# Pymodbus3: How to specify a slave's ID in Modbus Serial Client

Tags: python, serial-port, modbus

I am trying to connect my computer to a Modbus serial connection using pymodbus3 but I am not able to specify the slave_id to each request. I have been reading the code and I have seen that pymodbus3 always work with slave's ID 1 (unit_id in the code). This is good if you only have a one-to-one connection.

Thanking in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me with pymodbus3

```
rr = client.read_holding_registers(0x5B00,100, unit=0x02)
```